# Open Source data streaming engine

Tags: java, open-source, streaming

Are there any open source data streaming products for publishing and subscribing to objects?

A commercial example is [SwissRisk Slingshot](http://slingshot.swissrisk.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use [JGroups](http://www.jgroups.org/), a toolkit for reliable multicast communication.

Comment: JGroups Can be used for file serving?

Answer (score 1):

The [Ajax Push Engine](http://www.ape-project.org/) looks like what you're after.

Comment: APE is for use in web browsers only, i want something that can be used in a Java application. The library encapsulates the http calls, such that i register listeners and handle new data events.

Comment: That's what javax.script.ScriptEngine is for.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the recently released public Apache project called "Storm".

Storm is a real-time analytics engine that was originally developed at BackType, a company that was acquired by Twitter last year. After the acquisition, Twitter allowed lead developer Nathan Marz to finish the project and open source it. Twitter is now using Storm internally.

Here is an overview:
http://techcrunch.com/2012/07/18/twitter-storm-nodeable-pivot/

Source Code can be found here:
https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/

Comment: please add a link to the project.